# how to insert choice fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i have to use two choice fields from Language_list. 
so, i want to add or replace ------ with each choice's title in Language_list.

```
def __init__(self, auto_id='%s', *args, **kwargs):
```

is not woring in my forms....

i did not mean this bring error. 
it is still running ,but it is nothing to change.

here, my model and my list in my model

```
Language_list=( 
    ('AFRIKAANS','Afrikaans'),
    ('ALBANIAN','Albanian'), 
    ('AMHARIC','Amharic'),
    ('ARABIC','Arabic'),
     ....)
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    .....
    Mother_language = models.CharField(max_length = 30,choices= Language_list,null = False)
    Wish_language =models.CharField(max_length = 30,choices= Language_list,null = False)
 .....
```

this is my form

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}) )
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password confirmation'}))


    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        def __init__(self, auto_id='%s', *args, **kwargs):
            super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['Mother_language'].choices = [('', ('Mother_language '))] + models.Language_list
            self.fields['Wish_language'].choices = [('', ('Wish_language '))] + models.Language_list
            widgets = {
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':30,'placeholder': 'Email'}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':30,'placeholder': 'UserName'}),


    }

    fields = ('email','username','Mother_language','Nationality','Wish_language','picture')
```

Comment: you haven't stated or posted the error, you just said something is not working, no traceback or further explanations.

Comment: but there is no error... but did not change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an indentation error. Try this:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}) )
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password confirmation'}))


    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email','username','Mother_language','Nationality','Wish_language','picture')

    def __init__(self, auto_id='%s', *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Mother_language'].choices = [('', ('Mother_language '))] + models.Language_list
        self.fields['Wish_language'].choices = [('', ('Wish_language '))] + models.Language_list
        widgets = {
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':30,'placeholder': 'Email'}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':30,'placeholder': 'UserName'}),
        }
```